# how to use progressbar without using thread and handler?

Tags: android

How to use Progressbar without using thread and handler? 
i used following code but this is not working.

```
ProgressDialog prd=new ProgressDialog(this);
prd.setTitle("Please Wait........");
prd.show();
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working? Please, be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private class SomeTask extends AsyncTask {
private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(SomeActivity.this);

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    this.dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.someMessage));
    this.dialog.show();
}


@Override
protected List<Object> doInBackground(Object... objects) {
                ....
                try {
                // some logic here
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (this.dialog.isShowing()) this.dialog.dismiss();
            }

    return list;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    if (this.dialog.isShowing()) this.dialog.dismiss();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Progress dialog is always used to show that there is some background task going on when the prgress dialog is showing . There is no purpose of progress dialog without this.

However you can use **AsyncTask class** as a substitute of thread and handler to show progress dialog  in android.

See [this](http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/05/android-asynctask-example/) for AsyncTask class.

Answer (score 0):

Progress bar and progress dialog is different.

You can create progress bar through xml also. See the following code to craete progress bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/FIL_Main_RelativeLayout"
    android:background="#ffffff">
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse"
        android:id="@+id/FIL_Middle_ProgressBar"></ProgressBar>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: and you can  set the Visibility to GONE when you want to hide it after a while :) ; progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);